# Commenting out a specific host configuration in a Nagios configuration file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression, nagios

I have lots of Nagios configuration files like the one below in a directory, and I need to remove a host from monitoring.

```
define host{
    host_name nmo
    use aix-server
    alias
    hostgroups +bu-automotive-aerospace-prd,screen-automotive-aerospace-prd2
    address 10.18.15.7
}
```

What normally I do to remove a host from monitoring is this:

1) Find the host configuration file:

```
root@XXXXX:/home/rakesh/host_decom# grep -irow nmo hosts*
hosts-automotive.cfg:nmo
```

2) Comment the configuration lines:

```
vim hosts-automotive.cfg
```

[image]

3) Save the file, and the task has been completed.

How can I automate this process using a script?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: Do you want me send the text?

Comment: Apologies, if you found my words rude.
I am new in Regular expressions and trying just to replace a specific configuration with # comments

Comment: I am able to extract the configuration using -

perl -0777 -ne '/([^\n]*{[^}]*(hostname)[^}]*})/ && print "$1\n"' file_name

Now just trying to replace it with # comment in each line

Comment: @RakeshKumar What Tomasz means is that you should replace the screenshots in your question with the actual text content. There are several reasons for this, such as images being unfriendly for mobile devices.

Comment: @Haxiel, I have replaced first snap shot but not able to do the same with 2nd because of formatting. No difference only added # in each line

Comment: @RakeshKumar I have made an edit to your question to make your intent a bit clearer. Please add the contents of the second file to the question as well. You can use the 'Code' formatting option to fix any formatting errors.